# SQL replace 2-3 letter value in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with contacts and their key skills where values are divided by a semicolon:

[image: contact table]

And I can't figure out how to replace short key skills without harming the existing longer skills. E.g. **UI** is included in word B**ui**lding

For more than 4 letters I'm using below SQL script to replace value1 (@current) for value2 (@replace) just fine

```sql
DECLARE @current varchar(50) = 'UI'
DECLARE @replace varchar(50) = 'New Skill'
UPDATE database.dbo.contact
SET key_skill = CASE
    WHEN key_skill LIKE '%'+@replace+'%'+@current THEN REPLACE(key_skill, ';'+@current, '')
    WHEN key_skill LIKE '%'+@current+'%'+@replace THEN REPLACE(key_skill, @current+';', '')
    WHEN (key_skill LIKE '%'+@replace+'%'+@current+'%') OR (key_skill LIKE '%'+@current+'%'+@replace+'%') THEN REPLACE(key_skill, @current+';', '')
    WHEN key_skill LIKE '%'+@current+'%' THEN REPLACE(key_skill, @current, @replace)
    ELSE key_skill END
FROM database.dbo.contact
WHERE (key_skill LIKE '%'+@current+'%')
```

Comment: I'd imagine that in order to avoid corrupting other temrs you'll have to split each row's `key_skill` value and match on the whole word results within the split, and then rejoin those terms and update the column.  What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Did you try current = 'UI;' instead of 'UI' ? (with semicolon)

Comment: @squillman i hoped that i can avoid something like that, haha, but might be the only way, thank you, version is: 13.0.5103.6

Comment: @IsaAtaseven this works for some but the positions are always random that is why i'm using many conditions in case when, UI could be last without semicolon

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL Server, however I assume you can use regular expressions. Instead of LIKE '%UI%' you could try LIKE '%(UI)%' it should only match what you want it to :)

Comment: Fully agree with @GarethD's answer.  One thing that I will add is that make sure you have a way to escape the semicolon itself if it appears in the word.  You may not think you'll need this, but the history of computer science is full of people thinking they're clever and creating encoding schemes that only allow certain characters and blocks other, thinking that's all they'll need, only to be proven wrong in the future and have to desperately retrofit their scheme to make it work.  Don't make the same mistake they did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is at all possible you should change your design as soon as possible. There is almost never a good reason to store lists as delimited strings in a database. Databases already have the perfect structure for storing lists, they are called tables. A second table that links contacts to skills will be really useful here. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Contact
(
    ContactID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Contact__ContractID PRIMARY KEY (ContactID)
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.KeySkill
(
    KeySkillID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_KeySkill__KeySkillID PRIMARY KEY (KeySkillID)
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.ContactKeySkill
(
    ContactID INT NOT NULL,
    KeySkillID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ConactKeySkill__ContactID_KeySkillID PRIMARY KEY (ContactID, KeySkillID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ContactKeySill__ContactID FOREIGN KEY (ContactID) REFERENCES dbo.Contact (ContactID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ContactKeySill__KeySkillID FOREIGN KEY (KeySkillID) REFERENCES dbo.KeySkill (KeySkillID)
);
```

With this structure in place everything else becomes significantly easier. You can recreate your existing format if needed as follows:

```
SELECT  c.ContactID, c.Name, Skills = STRING_AGG(ks.Name, ';')
FROM    dbo.Contact AS c
        INNER JOIN dbo.ContactKeySkill AS cks
            ON cks.ContactID = c.ContactID
        INNER JOIN dbo.KeySkill AS ks
            ON ks.KeySkillID = cks.KeySkillID
GROUP BY c.ContactID, c.Name;
```

You are also in complete control of ordering and filtering (with indexes), and data integrity (no duplicates, or typos etc).

Adding/removing skills becomes as simple as inserting/deleting rows rather than having to do any string manipulation.

And if you decided you wanted to rename a skill, e.g. "UI" with "User Interface" well, again that is really really easy in a properly designed database:

```
UPDATE  dbo.KeySkill
SET     Name = 'User Interface'
WHERE   Name = 'UI';
```

Because you have now separated all your data, you can be certain that when you update `UI` there are no side effects because that is the only value stored in that field.

**[Working Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd9858279e2cc069aca18a42da2d0ab1)**

---

If you are not in control of your design and can't make these changes, then the following should work for you:

```
STUFF(key_skill, 
        CHARINDEX(CONCAT(';', @current, ';'),CONCAT(';', key_skill, ';')), 
        LEN(@current), 
        @replace);
```

The premise is that if you add `;` to the start and the end of both your `key_skill` string and your `@current` parameter, then it doesn't matter whether the term is at the start or the end of the string, you would be looking for `;UI;` in `;UI;PHP;Building;`, so the search term no longer matches in `building`.

It is easier to use [`STUFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) here rather than `REPLACE()`, just so you don't have to actually build a string with semi-colons on the end, then remove them at the end. All you need is to use `CHARINDEX` to find out where the skill starts in the string (2nd argument in stuff), the length of the skill (3rd argument), and use this as the starting point to "stuff" your new string in (4th argument).

**Demo**

```
CREATE TABLE #T (Contact VARCHAR(255), key_skill VARCHAR(255));
INSERT  #T(Contact, key_skill)
VALUES
    ('John Doe', 'AI;UI;ONC;BI;PHP'),
    ('Craig Smith', 'UI;PHP;Building'),
    ('Loren Paul', 'AI;UI');

DECLARE @current VARCHAR(50) = 'UI',
        @replace VARCHAR(50) = 'New Skill'

UPDATE  #T
SET key_skill = STUFF(key_skill, 
                    CHARINDEX(CONCAT(';', @current, ';'),CONCAT(';', key_skill, ';')), 
                    LEN(@current), 
                    @replace)
WHERE  CHARINDEX(CONCAT(';', @current, ';'),CONCAT(';', key_skill, ';')) > 0;

SELECT *
FROM #T;
```

---

**ADENDUM**

Since you can't change your data structure a more robust method of doing this will be to deconstruct your delimited list (using `STRING_SPLIT()`), then make your changes, then reconstruct it again (using `STRING_AGG()`), e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (Contact VARCHAR(255), key_skill VARCHAR(255));
INSERT  #T(Contact, key_skill)
VALUES
    ('John Doe', 'AI;UI;ONC;BI;PHP'),
    ('Craig Smith', 'UI;PHP;Building'),
    ('Loren Paul', 'AI;UI');

DECLARE @current VARCHAR(50) = 'UI',
        @replace VARCHAR(50) = 'New Skill'

UPDATE  t
SET     t.key_skill = s.NewList
FROM    #T AS t
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  STRING_AGG(Value, ';')
            FROM    (   SELECT  Value
                        FROM    STRING_SPLIT(t.key_skill, ';') AS s
                        WHERE   s.value <> @current
                        UNION
                        SELECT  @replace
                        WHERE   @replace <> ''
                    ) AS s

        ) AS s (NewList);
```

Where no `@current` value is specified this will simply add a skill, and where no `@replace` is set, then this will just remove the `@current`.

**[Working Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f805c15c88dddf4f9f56571f1482dda7)**

---

**ADENDUM 2**

For SQL Server 2016 that doesn't support `STRING_AGG()` you can use XML extensions as an alternative:

```
DECLARE @current VARCHAR(50) = 'UI',
        @replace VARCHAR(50) = 'New Skill'

UPDATE  t
SET     t.key_skill = STUFF(s.NewList.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    #T AS t
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  CONCAT(';', Value)
            FROM    (   SELECT  Value
                        FROM    STRING_SPLIT(t.key_skill, ';') AS s
                        WHERE   s.value <> @current
                        UNION
                        SELECT  @replace
                        WHERE   @replace <> ''
                    ) AS s
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) AS s (NewList);
```

Comment: Dammit.  Beat me to it on both answers :)
Agreed.  Separate table is best option,  concatenating the delimiter at the beginning and end of the full list is 2nd best.

Comment: I totally understand that design should be changed, but sadly I'm not in control of it at the moment. Thank you so much for your solutions! I have 2 questions to second one 1) if 'replace' value already exist in table, can it also avoid creating duplicates? 2) when 'current' doesn't exist it deletes all values

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? I ask because if you are using SQL Server 2016+ solving both issues is much easier than if you are using earlier versions.

Comment: SQL Server version: 13.0.5103.6

Comment: I've added a bit more information to the answer to show how you can prevent duplicates and also use the same process to add/remove skills, rather than just replace them.

Comment: Unfortunately STRING_AGG doesn't work on SQL Server 2016 but it is exactly what I needed + it can sort alphabetically which is awesome. I guess I'm stuck to create with XML path or upgrade server?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, but it's not a massive change to use the XML extensions. I've again updated the answer to show how this could be done

Comment: You have UNION ALL here by mistake? (dbfiddle is correct) I needed to also run it from database that have compatibility level 130 (for STRING_SPLIT). Everything works now, massive thanks Gareth!

Comment: Yep, `UNION ALL` was an error. I've removed that.